# How to create multi stacks in java

Tags: java

I want to create many stacks using for or while but I don't have any idea.

Ex:

```
Stack<...> stack_1 = new Stack<>();
Stack<...> stack_2 = new Stack<>();
...
Stack<...> stack_n = new Stack<>();
```

Create as above is very slowly. So, I want to have an idea to create quickly many stack by for or while such as:

```
for (...) {
    Create stack(index) ...
}
```

Comment: You can make an array of stacks. Then use a loop to initialize every array element.

Comment: Interesting ... you are already learning about a more sophisticated data structure like a stack; but nobody has told you about arrays, or ArrayList?

Answer (score 4):

```
List<Stack<Something>> stacks = new ArrayList<>(1000);
for (int i = 0; i < 1000; i++) {
   stacks.add(new Stack<Something>());
}
```

Comment: All stack use one or more memory ?